# Python - return or print none types on exception

Tags: python

```
   return str(self.id)+"-Vacancy for "+self.title+" at "+self.company.company_name or str(self.id)+"-Vacancy for "+self.title or self.id
```

I have a few variables some of which can be of None type. How can I print them without throwing exceptions or having try catch blocks.

Answer (score 1):

You could build a response string like the following

```
ret = ""
ret += str(self.id) if self.id is not None else ""
ret += "-Vacancy for "
ret += self.title if self.title is not None else ""
ret += self.company.company_name if self.company.company_name is not None else ""
return ret
```

Or define a `function` and **parse** each item, like the following:

```
def parsed(string):
   return string if string is not None else ""

(...)

return parsed(str(self.id))+"-Vacancy for "+parsed(self.title)+" at "+parsed(self.company.company_name or str(self.id))+"-Vacancy for "+parsed(self.title or self.id)
```